# Binary String to Binary Type in Python

Tags: python, binary

I have a binary string "b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x0".

```
binary_strig = "b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x0"
type(binary_strig)
str
```

I need to get a binary type in python:

```
binary_variable = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x0"
type(binary_variable)
binary
```

Please help how to cast or transfor str python to binary type

Comment: This is not a valid literal of bytes...

Comment: There is no *"binary type"* in Python.

Comment: Is a bytes type

Comment: Hi @ANGHELO if is bytes type and not binary type please EDIT your question. thanks :)

Comment: Having a string like "b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x0" is the result of a coding mistake, calling `str()` on a `bytes()` instance instead of calling the bytes instance's `.decode()` method.  Find where your code is making this mistake and fix it.  Calling python with the `-b` or `-bb` flags may help (`python -bb myscript.py`).